How to get nullable non-primitive parameters working with ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
Given this controller code:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public string Get([FromQuery]TestInput? testInput)
    {
        return "OK";
    }
}

public class TestInput
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

How do I make /test route work?
Currently I'm getting this:
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "Value": [
            "The Value field is required."
        ]
    },
    "traceId": "00-a6893dc23be5689c4b2219faf6f0e705-5fa0968422975595-00"
}

Implying that ? wasn't honored.
Note: I can get it working by making string properties on my model nullable, but that's not what I want as it's a mess. I could possibly get some luck with QueryStringValueProvider as suggested in this post, but that seems like overkill given the caliber of the issue. I'd like to get as codeless as possible solution for this rather a simple problem.

What happens if you set nullas the default value for testInput? I.e. public string Get([FromQuery]TestInput? testInput = null)

it's exactly the same, I tried it of course. Being a senior dev (I'm not being sarcastic) - can you tell me of any cases when Do(Type? type) behavior would differ from Do(Type type = null) when handling nulls? I'm just curious to know... Looking at the error it seems to ignore the fact that the parameter is nullable. Here's another one from 2017 on the same issue: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/555 I'm just too lazy but wouldn't be surprised if Swagger treats it as mandatory still.

And the biggest question I have why such a simple and highly intuitive solution as "?" doesn't work? There must be something deeper which I just fail to see.

Side question, I'm curious here about passing a custom complex type as a query parameter, how would you actually pass it in the query without some mapping configuration? e.g. what to put instead of ??? here: /test?testInput=???

Simple Prop=Value&Prop1=Value1 is taken care of by ASP.NET and converges to {Prop:Value, Prop1=Value1}. It works with non-nullable URLs, like in my case /test?value=Blah works just fine (well, boolean values require true/false and won't take 1/0 but that's a minor one).

Thanks, didn't know about this! and sorry for not being helpful regarding your issue here.

Seeing as you have TestInput? in your code I assume you're using <Nullable>enable</Nullable> in your .csproj file?

this is enabled by default and I have it.

I reproduced your issue and found a couple of things that worked, courtesy of this answer.
It seems that properties that are reference types have implicit required attributes when they are not nullable, so either disable this implicity:
services.AddControllers(o => o.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);

Or make the property nullable.
public class TestInput
{
    public string? Value { get; set; }
}

